# Can an inductor lose its characteristics permanently after short saturation?

Tags: power-supply, magnetics, saturation

I was testing a SMPS (boost) where I had an overcurrent due to overload for a few seconds.

The inductor saturation current is 2A.

Although I could not measure the current, I am quite sure that the current was a few times higher than the saturation current.

I was able to switch off everything within a few seconds.

After that I removed the load and the converter works fine under no load.

However, when I connected a load which was previously working fine, the converter is not able to deliver the current and goes crazy.

Basically same behaviour as in the "failure/overcurrent" case.

I checked and inspected all the components, they look fine.

So based on this my hypothesis would be that the short "failure/overcurrent" has changed the inductor characteristics. In particular the saturation current has lowered.

I could not find any information online whether this is physically possible. 
Is there anyone who can shed some light on this?

(I am using a shielded  SMD box inductor.)

BTW: Unfortunately, I don't have an LCR meter to measure the inductance.

Comment: Now would be the time to get one (an LCR meter).

Comment: What makes you think it's the inductor?  I would be more suspect of the controls/switches.

Comment: @DaveTweed :) I guess your right

Comment: @calcium3000 , the IC used has an external MOSFET, so since it operating under no load, I do not think it is the IC or the MOSFET.

Comment: I don't think that over-saturation will change the characteristics. Unless you overheated it enough to crack the core. Can you measure the current that is charging the inductor?  Use a current probe, or put a small resistor in series with the MOSFET. The slope of the rising ramp should be Vs/L. If the inductor is saturating, the current will spike at the end of the ramp.

Comment: There are also alternatives to an LCR meter if you have an oscilloscope and a signal generator.  Or even a good AC voltmeter and a signal generator.

Comment: If the AC pulse approaches L/R = tau time , the magnetic flux can not reset and current continues to rise into saturation when L drops impedance and thus leads to thermal runaway.

Comment: It's far more likely that you've damaged the MOSFET.  It *is* possible to change the characteristics of a device (usually for the worse) without destroying it completely.

Comment: High power SMPS typically have  startup logic before they power up completely. You have in all probability killed something in your high power switch path, but the startup logic is still working at no load. Look at your switch FET or it's driver.

Comment: Possible reason is short of indutor winding (less inductance), or partial Mosfet breakdown.